# nifi: how to merge multiple columns in csv file?

Tags: apache-nifi

nifi version: 1.5

input file:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
a,hr,nat,REF,6,2481
a,hr,nat,TDB,6,1845
b,IT,raj,NAV,6,2678
```

i want to merge the last three columns with : delimiter and separator by / based on col1.

expected output:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
a,hr,nat,REF:6:2481/TDB:6:1845
b,IT,raj,NAV:6:2678
```

i am not able to find the solution because lot of response were based merging two files.
is there a better way to do it?

tia.

Comment: are the cvs files large?

Comment: approximately it would contain 1 lakh records in csv file.

Comment: i don't see the straight way, only scripting... but this could be heavy for memory because of the large file.

Comment: @daggett i am planning to use scripting way. because i know python, not jython. it seems that executestreamcommand/executeprocess can execute the python as same way as command line. Jython uses executescript processor. is my understanding right? do you have any reference to read flowfiles to the executestreamcommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want a PartitionRecord processor first, with partition field `col1`, this will split the flow file into multiple flow files where each distinct value of `col1` will be in its own flow file. If the first 3 columns are to be used for partitioning, you can add all three columns as user-defined properties for partitioning.

Then whether you use a scripted solution or perhaps QueryRecord (if Calcite supports "group by" concatenation), the memory usage should be less as you are only dealing with a flow file at a time whose rows are already associated by the specified group.

Comment: thanks for your response. this works SELECT col4||':'||col5||':'||col6 FROM FLOWFILE instead of CONCAT.